# Android Studio 2.3 failed find build tools

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm getting mad, after updating android studio 2.2 to 2.3 i can't create and edit any project because gradle get error:

```
Failed to find build tools revision 26.0.0 or any versions
```

I downloaded Gradle and build tools from android studio also but didn't work.

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26

    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "atys.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

and:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should Update Your Tools with the SDK Manager First .
Look This Link Its Helpful.
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

if your problem do not solve. uninstall your android studio and Delete you Sdk Folder and reinstall android studio new Version from this link: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html